# How to use spatial queries in google spanner

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, geospatial, google-cloud-spanner

Can we use geo spatial queries in google spanner DB? If not, is there any alternate way we can use spatial queries in SQL by moving spatial calculations in application server?

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Spanner doesn't currently support geospatial queries, but might in the future.

One way to implement it yourself is using something like [Google's S2 library](http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/) to map your geopoints into S2 cells, as an example. You can then use this same format to convert your queries to check against this geohash.

If you don't need Spanner's scale, perhaps a Cloud SQL Postgres instance would be better.

Comment: Do you guys support geospatial indexes yet?